# How to define this large object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

The main function parses a file, and returns a large object.

```
function parse(file){
/* dostuff.. */
return myObject
}
```

The properties are determined sequentially (i.e "a" has to be determined before "b" or value will differ). This is a minimal example:

```
type MyObject = {a:number, b:number, c:string} //long list of keys..
function parse():MyObject{
let myObject:{[key:string]:any} = { }
myObject.a = 'hello';
myObject.b = 5;
myObject.c = 55;
//...
return myObject as MyObject
}
```

But **myObject.a** should be a number and it is a string (opposite for **myObject.c**). Hence the type checking isn't useful.

How should this be refactored? Declaring each property as a `const prop:type=value` first?

Comment: The compiler is just doing what you told it to: `{[key:string]:any}` means that the object properties can be any string referencing any type at all. If you want `myObject` keys to *only* point at number values but don't care about the keys, use `Record<string, number>` if there are only certain meaningful names then you'll have to specify them.

Comment: Are you just looking for `Partial<MyObject>`? Or is there something specific about the order of setting properties that you need to capture?

Comment: @jcalz yes the props have to be defined in that exact order. I don't know about Partial<MyObject> but I will take a look.

Comment: I see you accepted the other answer but nothing in there ensures the ordering (e.g., you could easily write `const myObject: MyObject = { c, b, a }` or `myObject.c = 55; myObject.b = 5; myObject.a = 'hello';` and there'd be no compiler warning.  So either you don't really need the compiler to capture something about ordering, or you have erroneously accepted an answer that doesn't meet your needs.  Which is it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. None of those; maybe I didn't explain well enough. By "ordering" I meant **a** has to be defined before **b**. The position in the object is irrelevant. @jcalz

Comment: Since you can write [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJRYZW) and have no compiler error, then it really does seem like you don't need the *compiler* to care about the ordering.  There doesn't seem to be anything anywhere that guarantees `a` will be defined before `b`.  If that's not true, can you demonstrate what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not allow partially implementing type requirements, – either you implement them all together, or you make some of the requirements optional in the first place.

The first approach ("all together") would look like this:

```
type MyObject = { a: string, b: number, c: number };

function main(): MyObject {
  // `myObject` does not exist yet,
  // first we have to gather necessary data
  const a: string = "Hello world";
  const b: number = 42;
  const c: number = 17;

  // now we can create `myObject`
  const myObject: MyObject = { a, b, c };

  return myObject;
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/WPxaYW).*

The second approach ("make some of the requirements optional") is as follows:

```
type MyObject = { a: string, b: number, c: number };

function main(): MyObject {
  // `myObject` exists, but it is not yet fully implemented
  const myObject: Partial<MyObject> = {};

  // add all the missing data to `myObject`
  myObject.a = "Hello world";
  myObject.b = 42;
  myObject.c = 17;

  // "shut up, TypeScript, I know it is done now"
  return myObject as MyObject;
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/w8KR9W).*

Arguably, you should go with the first approach whenever possible.

Comment: Yes, I am following approach 1 as described, thanks for the second option, which I don't like but should understand better. Isn't the last line "as MyObject" unnecessary as that's already declared on the function's "head"?

Comment: It is necessary though, because `Partial<MyObject>` does not meet all requirements of `MyObject` (i.e., some of its properties might be missing, which would [break the contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)). I've added playground links for the snippets; you could remove `as MyObject` and see the compile error.